# Open network folder from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am trying to open a network folder from my html page. An UNC path is coming from the backend in the following fashion:

```
\\volume\sharedname
```

I am using the following code to open the location:

```
'<a target="_blank" href="' + 'file:///' + '\\volume\sharedname' + '">'test'</a>';
```

It would work in IE, but in Chrome I get:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file://volume\sharedname
```

Is there any chance to open a network folder running the above code in Chrome?

Thanks

Comment: can the web server serve the files instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On Windows Operating System**
Get the url of your Chrome Installation path to your chrome installation e.g C:\Users-your-user-name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application>
Launch the Google Chrome browser from the command line window with the additional argument ‘–allow-file-access-from-files’. E.g ‘path to your chrome installation\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files’
Temporary method you can use each time you are testing
- Copy the existing chrome launcher
- Do as above and save it with a new name e.g chrome - testing
- Alternatively, you can simply create a new launcher with the above and use it to start chrome.

**On Linux Operating System (specifically UBUNTU)**
Slightly Permanent Method

Go to the menu entry/ launcher for Chrome (.desktop file)
Open the launcher properties dialog.
It should look something like this: ‘/usr/bin/google-chrome %U’
Change it to ‘/usr/bin/google-chrome --allow-access-from-files‘ to make the flags work permanently
You may also need to delete and re-pin your launcher(s) after modifying it. Chrome should launch with the specified flags enabled after the modification.

**Note:** That flag can be dangerous. It leaves your file system open for access. Documents originating from anywhere, local or web, should not, by default, have any access to local file:/// resources.

Comment: I also found that I can add a locallink extension to Chrome. I did it and now it opens my  network folder, but only as a direct click on the link. Is there any chance to open network link using windows.open command?