# Open network path in browser in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am unable to open network path from browser using below code. Browser throws error saying unable to load local resources. Please advise.

```
    public openUrl() {
    window.open(`file:///server/folder1/filelist`);
  }



<a title="{{summaryValues.TraceLogPath}}"
                                href="javascript:void(0)"  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                (click)="openUrl()">{{BenchmarkTraceLog}}</a>
```

Comment: Whatever are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to open shared path that shows list of files. BenchmarkTraceLog contains network path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open network folder from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088657/open-network-folder-from-html)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't let us access the local resource.
1. Disabling file security is the option to access data from shared path.
2. Usage of API will do the needful.